# Why does my 2D array only omit some of the elements when sorted and omitted elements are also not sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
class Temp
{

    static void sort1(int x[][])           //sort 2d  array
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<x[i].length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=i;k<x.length;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j;l<x[k].length;l++)
                    {
                        if(x[i][j] > x[k][l])
                        {
                            temp = x[i][j];
                            x[i][j] = x[k][l];
                            x[k][l] = temp;
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(".....Sorted Array.....");
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<x[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + "  ");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        sort1(new int[][] { 
            {12, 7, 65}, 
            {87, 1, 4, 5, 31}, 
            {9, 76} 
            });
    }
}
```

When I'm running this program it is giving the output as

`1  4  5  7  12  31  65`.

I expected it to be

`1  4  5  7  9  12  31  65  76  87`.

What is wrong with my code?
It's missing results that it should be showing. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you debugged the code?

Comment: It's giving unexpected results every time. I changed elements of the array that I'm passing as an argument. It even not printing all the elements.

Comment: At which specific line number, while debugging, did you observe that the results were unexpected based on what you expected to see?

Comment: I think something is wrong with loops!

Comment: Don't think we're understanding each other. Start here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html If you don't use Eclipse, search `[IDE NAME] debugging` in Google

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I'm not using any IDE. I compile them on cmd.

Comment: You have two choices: Get an IDE with a built in debugger (they're all mostly free), or use a pen and paper. Harder, but definitely still doable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here are the bugs I could spot:

1. When you output the result, in the inner loop you need to start with `0` and not `i` as you want to process all the elements of the array and not only its half under the main diagonal

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<x[i].length;j++)
       {
           System.out.print(x[i][j] + "  ");
       }
   }
   ```
2. The same thing with the second loop in your sorting phase: it must start with `0`, the reason is the same

   `for(int j=0;j<x[i].length;j++)`
3. There is a problem with sorting. In one-dimentional case, you'd have two loops, and the inner one would start with `i` (where `i` is the index of the outer loop). In your 2-dimentional case, two outer loops stand for the only outer loop of 1-dimensional case, and two inner loops stand for the only inner loop of 1-dimensional case. Your 2 inner loops need to iterate over all the remaining elements of row `i` till the end (columns `j` to the last), plus all the rest rows (rows from `i+1` to the last, indices from 0 to the last). But instead you iterate over elements from `j` to last in **all** the remaining rows, so you miss some elements (which reside in columns between `0` and `j-1` in rows `i` to the last one).

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much, MAN!
Actually, i made a one-dimensional array program and then I made this two-dimensional array sort program. And i was putting same logic on 2D array program.

Comment: I just found why all the elements are not printing.
       `for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<x[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(x[i][j] + "  ");
            }
        }`

Comment: j=i should be replaced by j=1

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to StackOverflow.
Don't know how to indent comments and all.